# how to compare in #if condition of preprocessor for string

Tags: c-preprocessor

Hi my c code need to consider block of code depending on

```
#if <condition>
 //code block to execute if conditions matches
#endif
```

Now problem is in my shell script which I run before I compile c  code I set ML_ARCH=r8.
I can do check in Makefile as below:

```
ifeq ($(ML_ARCH), r8)
endif
```

But for C code how to compare variable against string which is mix of char and number, in preprocessor #if

Answer (score 1):

> how to compare in #if condition of preprocessor for string

It is not possible to compare strings in preprocessor.

---

You can add something unique to `r8` to make it longer and define it to a number. You could just `#define r8 1`, but `r8` is a bit short and could be break random code.

```
// #define ML_ARCH   r8

#define ARCH_r8               1
#define ARCH_some_other_arch  2
#define ARCH_etc              3

#define XADD_ARCH(a) ARCH_##a
#define ADD_ARCH(a)  XADD_ARCH(a)    
#define IS_ARCH(a)   (ADD_ARCH(ML_ARCH) == ARCH_##a)

// #if XCONCAT(ARCH_, ML_ARCH) == ARCH_r8
#if IS_ARCH(r8)
```

Overall, consider doing `-D ML_ARCH=ARCH_r8` and then just `#if ML_ARCH == ARCH_r8`.